# cakephp 3 i18n translations not loading in the model

Tags: php, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

Help!
So, I did every step from the documentation.

**1.** Added behavior to the table model

```
public function initialize(array $config) { 
    $this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['title']]);
```

**2.** Added trait to entity model

```
class Article extends Entity {
    use TranslateTrait;
```

**3.** I created the i18n table using the sql code from the cake documentation.

```
    CREATE TABLE i18n (
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    locale varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    model varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    foreign_key int(10) NOT NULL,
    field varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    content text,
    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX I18N_LOCALE_FIELD(locale, model, foreign_key, field),
    INDEX I18N_FIELD(model, foreign_key, field)
);
```

**4.** Created inputs like this (based on the cake documentation):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('_translations.fr.title') ?>
```

When I submit the form, everything is saved properly in the i18n table.
    [i18n table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHsEw.png)

BUT!, when I try to read the translation it's not there.
I do it like this:

```
$article = $this->Articles->get($id);
```

I can read every attribute but the translated ones.

This code returns null:

```
<?php var_dump($article->translation('fr')->title); ?>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that 
`$article = $this->Articles->get($id);`
do not include the translations.

Instead I use
`$this->Articles->find('translations')->where(['id', $id])->first();`